# Adding new disk to VM after VM is protected

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery

I've set up Azure Site Recovery to replicate a VM using Azure-to-Azure replication. Everything is working great, but I've now added a new disk to my VM and I do not see the .vhd page blob in the replicated storage account.

How can I get the newly added disk to replicate? Do I need to remove replication and then redo it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this feature is not available. Probably you need to redo it.

You may vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/256299-site-recovery/suggestions/6438471-automatically-replicate-the-new-disk

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.